# Hacker Rank clone in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a Hacker rank clone project in React, and so far I tried to get all the New Posts from the API.
Since the API only gives me id's I was just able to map over the piece of state that holds that information. But now I want to get the whole data from every id that I got , and then display all the posts. It's been really confusing for me, and i really need some help. Well, to resume everything: I got the id's from a api call and stored it in my state. Now I want to get all of the id's and make another request, but this time I'll get the info based on that specific Id. Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import TopList from "./components/TopList";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: [23251319, 23251742, 23251158],
    results: []
  });

  const fetcher = id => {
    fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        setState({
          results: data
        });
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TopList data={state.data} fetcher={fetcher} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";

import Top from "./Top";

function TopList({ data, fetcher }) {
  const mapped = data.map(item => (
    <Top fetcher={fetcher} id={item} key={item} />
  ));

  return <div>{mapped}</div>;
}

export default TopList;
```

```
import React from "react";

function Top({ id, fetcher }) {
  fetcher(id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello from top</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Top;
```

Comment: Hi, what's your question exactly? Do you see any errors or is it that you don't know how to get the data of each ID?

Comment: I dont know how to do it, I want to get  the data that from the second request, wich is gonna be called by using every id  of the first call. For example: I get 200 ID's from the first request, and each id is going to be passed as the id in the fetcher function, wich is going to give me data about that specific id

Comment: Hmmm... The `fetcher()` function already gets the data of each ID, you just need to call it somewhere. I think a good place to do it is in `TopStoryComponent`, I'll write an answer with the code and let me know if it does what you need ^^

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in the comments, the `fetcher()` function already gets the data of each item using the IDs you have from the first request. I think that a good place to call this function is the `TopStoryComponent`, as there will be an instance of this component for each ID in the list.

```js
import React from "react";

function TopStoryComponent({ identification, fetcher }) {
  // this will print the data to the console
  fetcher(identification);

  return <div>{identification}</div>;
}

export default TopStoryComponent;
```

Let me know if it helps you get what you need!

Comment: I am making this project in a sandbox, and since the information being sent to me is so huge, I'm getting a lot of errors. I'll start from scratch, and try to think in another way, thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! Good luck with it, just keep working on it ^^

Comment: I managed to get some progress, but I'm facing a problem. I refactored the code and instead of just getting the info from the API, I provided some fake data. It made the app faster. but when I try to put the results inthe state i get the following error :

Comment: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like you tried to change the state of the component when it was not yet mounted. Check this link, it may help you https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/issues/434#issuecomment-449561024

Comment: I have to make sure that fetcher is available in the global scope, but calling it in the useeffect makes impossible to pass it as a prop to the To component